# Is it possible to share links via whatsapp and messenger.com using web interface?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, messenger

I mean, is there smth like `fb-messenger://share?link=link` and `whatsapp://send?text=text` but for messenger.com and web.whatsapp.com? 
Searched for that in their docs, but no results.

Comment: Have you got any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

For Whatsapp

```
 <a target="_blank" OnClick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=0,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=600,height=250'); return false;" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=hey check this out : http://www.qbitdata.in"><img src="./buttons/whatsapp.png" width="57" /></a>
```